# Display information from two separate lists in single CQWP?

Tags: 2010, list, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I am working on a project within a Sharepoint 2010 site. I have a list of items that are news articles, custom content type and columns. I also have a list for departments, these contain a variety of columns for information including text and images. I need to display the departments via a CQWP using a custom itemstyle. Within this itemstyle I want to also be able to display links to the news articles related to each department within their section on the page. Is it possible to display the information from two separate lists within a single content query webpart? If there is no OOTB solution I am open to suggestions on alternative ways to accomplish this.

EDIT: After some additional digging, I am curious if this could be achieved through creating a multi-value lookup column pointing to one of the lists. One of the issues with this approach is that it appears you cannot pull in a multiline text column in a lookup column. I absolutely need the information within that column to be pulled in. Is there a way that I could work around this limitation or is there an entirely different approach than the lookup column?